# Do I need to submit CCATS?

Tags: iphone, ios, encryption

I have a question about my app submission to itunes.

My app using 256 bit key encryption but not sending data to anywere. Encrypted data will remain on same IOS device only.

My question is, Do I need to submit commodity classification ruling (CCATS)?

Any help on this is much appreciated.

Thanks
Alok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If you application uses encryption (including SSL and HTTPS, possible
>   other public domain encryption) then you need to get at least get an
>   ERN before submitting your app to Apple for approval.

Source: http://tigelane.blogspot.in/2011/01/apple-itunes-export-restrictions-on.html

And also if you are using crypto libraries for your encryption that are already available on iphone than you don't need to submit CCATS and if you are using any public domain implementation than you will have to use it.

http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.in/2009/02/strong-encryption-for-cocoa-cocoa-touch.html